# Positioning ui-angular carousel controls

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, carousel

I am creating a carousel that displays images with some meta data. On md and lg screens I want the meta data to appear to the right, and on smaller screens I want it below the image, which is working fine using col-md-8 / col-md-4

Here is my carousel code:

```
        <uib-carousel active="active" interval="0" no-wrap="noWrapSlides" template-url="/Scripts/MainClient/views/cwCarouselTemplate.html"  style="height:100%">
            <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 " ng-style="{height: hackheight}" id="img-div">
                        <div style="padding:10px; height:100%;" class="black-bkgd">
                            <span class="helper"></span><img class="img-responsive " ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        Here's where the meta data goes go!
                        <h4>Slide {{slide.id}}</h4>
                    <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </uib-carousel>
```

The problem I have is regarding the right hand control - it is positioned to the right of the whole carousel, and I want it right relative to the col-md-8 div (so it appears over the right hand side of the image, not over the meta data). It works if I set right to be 34% on the control, but this then doesn't work on xs/sm screens (the control is in the middle of the image).

I can get it to the right position on either xs/sm screens (with right:0) OR on md/lg screens (with right:34%) but not on all screens at the same time!

One idea I had is to add a `<span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="width:34%"></span>` to the right to push the control over on larger screens but I can't get it to work - the span just stacks with the carousel control.

Here's the template I'm using:

```
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" ng-transclude></div>
        <a role="button" href class="left carousel-control" ng-click="prev()" ng-class="{ disabled: isPrevDisabled() }" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">previous</span>
        </a>
        <a role="button" href class="right carousel-control" ng-click="next()" ng-class="{ disabled: isNextDisabled() }" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">next</span>
        </a>
        <!--
        <ol class="carousel-indicators" ng-show="slides.length > 1">
          <li ng-repeat="slide in slides | orderBy:indexOfSlide track by $index" ng-class="{ active: isActive(slide) }" ng-click="select(slide)">
            <span class="sr-only">slide {{ $index + 1 }} of {{ slides.length }}<span ng-if="isActive(slide)">, currently active</span></span>
          </li>
        </ol>
        -->
    </div>
```

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Just a wild idea: why don't you wrap your buttons in a `col-md-8` div and set the position to absolute?

Comment: Wow, thanks so much - 6 hours of fiddling and the solution is so simple! I had to add a `col-xs-12` in there too to get it working, but `<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12" style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0; margin-left:15px">` is largely working (the only problem now is that when xs/sm the button heights are the height of img+meta div so are too low, but I'm sure I'll figure it out!). Please add as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap your buttons in a absolute positioned `col-md-8` to achieve the result.

If the element height remains an issue, you could provide a plunkr of your code, so we can look into that.